# Access 2013 Add multiple records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am creating a Training Records database.
Tables: EmployeeList, RolesPerformed, SkillsNeeded, Courses, EmployeeRoles (Junction of EmployeeList and RolesPerformed), RoleSkills (Junction of Roles and Skills), SkillCourses (Junction of Skills and Courses). I can query to find out what courses an employee needs based on their roles. But I need to make another table to track the courses per employee and their date completed. When creating an Employee the user sets their Roles. I would like to auto populate the EmployeeCourses table with the needed courses.

I tried to use an After Insert event on EmployeeRoles, but it claims a createRecord cannot be used in a foreachrecord.

Comment: I'd recommend an insert statement executed as CurrentDb.Execute, and if elaborated, that'd be a full answer... leaving this as a comment. :) I'd avoid using Docmd types of actions except when they are the only way to do something. In this case you can accomplish your task with greater control by means of SQL statements and/or recordset objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a table that defines what courses go with what roles?

The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into. Perhaps AfterUpdate for a combobox to select Role. Will probably also need code that first commits the new employee/role record to table.

VBA could be like:
`If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False 
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO EmployeeCourses(EmpID, CourseID) SELECT " & Me.tbxEmpID & " AS EID, CourseID FROM RolesCourses WHERE RoleID = " & Me.cbxRoleID`

To prevent duplicate employee/course entries, set compound index on the EmpID and CourseID fields in EmployeeCourses.